# how can i optimize SQL query

Tags: sql-server

i want to optimize below SQL query, its taking long time to get the desired output , i just post here the particular query which is taking long time to process.

currently don't have any index in the table, Please suggest how can i optimize this query to perform better also let me know if i want to create any index for the table

```
Insert into tbl_Details
    SELECT a.[COST],a.[Ch_Group] as 'CHGROUP',a.[PRODHIR],d.[MATERIAL],
    a.[UCC],
        CASE WHEN SUM(CAST(d.[Qty3] AS FLOAT))<='0.00000' THEN '0.00000'
        ELSE
         (
        SUM(CAST(d.[Qty3] AS FLOAT))/
        (SELECT (SUM(CAST(p.[Qty3] AS FLOAT))) AS 'SUM'
        FROM [tbl_OP6] p WHERE CAST(p.[Qty3] as FLOAT)>0 AND p.[PROD_HIER] LIKE a.[PRODHIR]+'%' 
        AND CONCAT(p.[Qty2],p.[Qty3A],p.[Qty4A]) LIKE case when a.[Ch_Group] like 'PM60%' then '%' else a.[Ch_Group]+'%' end and p.[zsdistrib] like a.[UCC]+'%' 
        AND  p.[PROD_HIER]LIKE a.[PRODHIR]+'%'  AND CAST(p.[Qty3] AS FLOAT)>'0.00000')
        )
        end
             AS 'GSV'
        ,'' as 'BUFCG'  
        FROM TEMP2_New a
        INNER JOIN [tbl_OP6] d ON CONCAT(d.[Qty2],d.[Qty3A],d.[Qty4A]) LIKE case when a.[Ch_Group] like 'PM60%' then '%' else a.[Ch_Group]+'%' end and d.[zsdistrib] like a.[UCC]+'%'
        AND  d.[PROD_HIER]LIKE a.[PRODHIR]+'%'  AND CAST(d.[Qty3] AS FLOAT)>'0.00000'
        WHERE a.[RULE]='4'
        GROUP BY a.[COST],a.[Ch_Group],a.[PRODHIR],d.[MATERIAL],a.[ORDERTYPE],
        a.[VALUEFIELD],a.[UCC],
        CONCAT(d.[Qty2],d.[Qty3A],d.[Qty4A]),a.[COORDER],a.[PLANT],a.[SEND_CCTR]
```

Comment: *"currently don't have any index in the table, Please suggest how can i optimize this query to perform better "* - index your table.

Comment: if you run this in SSMS with `actual execution plan` enabled, does it suggest any indexes to create ?

Comment: `CAST(d.[Qty3] AS FLOAT` in your `WHERE` isn't going to make a SARGable query either. Why are you converting it? Surely `Qty3` is already a numerical datatype. `CONCAT(d.[Qty2],d.[Qty3A],d.[Qty4A])` and then that `CASE` expression (which can resolve to `LIKE '%'`) is going to force a table scan too.

Comment: Dude, this horse is dead. Stop flogging it and think of some other, entirely different approach.

Comment: Why are there duplicated clauses in your subquery too? For example `AND p.[PROD_HIER] LIKE a.[PRODHIR] + '%'`. You proably, however, want to move that subquery into the `FROM`. There's a lot of problems with this query in all honesty.

Comment: i have created index suggested by execution plan but still it's slow,i think subquery in case statement may be problem but don't get any other idea to do this but requirement bit complicated and i m not very export in SQL but some how managed to get the output using this query, if possible some one plz post me optimized query

Comment: any update on this..any suggestion for which column i have create index to make performance better.any reference how can replace case statement like condition with any other approach..also want to ask one thing table don't have any primary key now, will it be faster if i create primary key

Answer (score 0):

The first item below will speed up your query the most by adding non-clustered indexes for the fields in your join statement.

1. Create a clustered index on table TBL_OP6 and another clustered index on table TEMP2_NEW.  This should speed up your query by 85% or so.  You could also check the recommended indexes to build using the Actual Execution Plan (ctrl + m, and then run the query, click the execution plan tab when the query finishes running, then hover your mouse cursor over the missing index section, and then click on missing index.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TBL_OP6_Clustered] ON [dbo].[TBL_OP6]
(
    QTY2 ASC,
    QTY3A ASC,
    QTY4A ASC,
    ZSDISTRIB ASC,
    PROD_HIER ASC,
    QTY3 ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TEMP2_NEW_Clustered] ON [dbo].[TEMP2_NEW]
(
    CH_GROUP ASC,
    UCC ASC,
    PRODHIR ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

2. Removing any indexes that exist on table TBL_DETAILS will increase the speed of the insert statement moderately.  Occasionally, dropping an index from the table, inserting the data, and then recreating the index could save some time.
3. Converting the field D.QTY3 to a Float in your database instead of casting it as a Float 6 times would speed up the query very slightly
4. Several LIKE statements are being used.  Instead, a table with a list of all possible values could be used, where the table has an index.
5. The indexes below would also be helpful if you're not concerned about the indexes taking up space, but probably won't speed up the query by too much.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TEMP2_NEW_NonClustered] ON [dbo].[TEMP2_NEW]
(
    [RULE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TTBL_OP6_NonClustered] ON [dbo].[TBL_OP6]
(
    QTY3 ASC,
    PROD_HIER ASC,
    QTY2 ASC,
    QTY3A ASC,
    QTY4A ASC,
    ZSDISTRIB ASC,
    PROD_HIER ASC,
    QTY3 ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I edited the script to make it readable:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_DETAILS
SELECT
    A.COST,
    A.CH_GROUP AS 'CHGROUP',
    A.PRODHIR,
    D.MATERIAL,
    A.UCC,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(CAST(D.QTY3 AS FLOAT)) <= '0.00000' THEN '0.00000'
        ELSE
        (
            SUM(CAST(D.QTY3 AS FLOAT)) /
            (
                SELECT
                (
                    SUM(CAST(P.QTY3 AS FLOAT))
                ) AS 'SUM'
                FROM TBL_OP6 P
                WHERE
                    CAST(P.QTY3 AS FLOAT) > 0
                    AND P.PROD_HIER LIKE A.PRODHIR + '%' 
                    AND CONCAT(P.QTY2, P.QTY3A, P.QTY4A) LIKE
                        CASE
                            WHEN A.CH_GROUP LIKE 'PM60%' THEN '%'
                            ELSE A.CH_GROUP+'%'
                        END 
                    AND P.ZSDISTRIB LIKE A.UCC + '%'
                AND P.PROD_HIER LIKE A.PRODHIR + '%'
                AND CAST(P.QTY3 AS FLOAT) > '0.00000'
            )
        )
    END AS 'GSV',
    '' AS 'BUFCG'
FROM TEMP2_NEW A
JOIN TBL_OP6 D ON
    CONCAT(D.QTY2, D.QTY3A, D.QTY4A) LIKE CASE WHEN A.CH_GROUP LIKE 'PM60%' THEN '%' ELSE A.CH_GROUP + '%' END
    AND D.ZSDISTRIB LIKE A.UCC + '%'
    AND D.PROD_HIER LIKE A.PRODHIR + '%'
    AND CAST(D.QTY3 AS FLOAT) > '0.00000'
WHERE A.RULE = '4'
GROUP BY A.COST, A.CH_GROUP, A.PRODHIR, D.MATERIAL, A.ORDERTYPE, A.VALUEFIELD,A.UCC,
    CONCAT(D.QTY2, D.QTY3A, D.QTY4A), A.COORDER, A.PLANT, A.SEND_CCTR
```